# How to insert vmstat output to a file maintaining a single entry always

Tags: linux, cron

I want to insert vmstat output to a file in every 10 seconds. I use the following command to do it.

```
vmstat 10 > vmstatfile.txt
```

This will create a file named vmstatfile.txt and appends to it, on every 10 seconds. What I want is, my file should always contain a single vmstat entry, the latest one, so that the file will not grow. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that: `watch --interval=10 "vmstat 1 1" > vmstatfile.txt`

Comment: It is creating an empty file. Have you tested it?

Comment: I have no vmstat in my linux environment right away to test. So I have tested using another command like `ls' and other. Perhaps you need to tune parameters of vmstat to exit after one print. I don't remember exactly what parameters they are. try to `"vmstat"` without any parameter. Or indicate what error message you get if any.